# Ubuntu Server Disk is full where there is still space left

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

We have an Ubuntu Server running and I installed SVN on it. We have been using the server for 4 or 5 months and we are assigned Appuser with sudo privileges.

The problem is, we are running out of space for appuser. As far as I understand, we have 3 different disks which are root, appuser and removable disk. The snapshot for the current level is as follows

[image: Ubuntu Disk Situation]

Now, I wonder how can I prevent this or solve my problem. I had to delete some useful programs in order to create 80.6 MB disk space (before, it was 0).

One option I can think of is to move SVN to root if doable. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. Other option might be to create a new user with root privileges in another directory.

Long story short, I need a way to manage the limited disk I am assigned. There are several servers like this and I am having this problem in each and every one them.

By the way, is there any way to increase the disk size of /dev/sda3 /home (appuser)? If I can add some additional disk space (from root or any other source) it will be very useful.

One last I can think of is, I cannot see what is under /var/opt/appuser even tough I connect with appuser. Only root can see it. Is this a problem?

I appreciate any hints and directions.

Comment: Create a symlink to a disk where you have space available.

Comment: can you give me details as I do not want to make a mistake. This a running server for production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native filesystems supported by the Linux kernel (namely, those of `extN` family) have the concept of *the space reserved for the superuser* (that with `UID` 0).  The idea is that when the filesystem appears to be full, and various programs start to fail due to this, the superuser still has certain scratch space available to perform recovery tasks (think of text editor's buffer swap/backup files, the need to copy files around etc). Hence what you're seeing here is the difference between what your root user sees and what your regular users see.

The typical reservation of free space is 5% when the filesystem is created (which was sensible back in the day, but not really these days, with multi-gigabyte or -terabyte filesysems). Luckily, this parameter might be tuned after the fact (using the `tune2fs` program for the `extN` filesystems). I usually set it manually to 100MiB after creating a typical reasonably large `extN` filesystem.

To see how many space is reserved, go like this:

1. Ask the filesystem about its current parameters:

   ```
   # tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -Ei 'reserved|block size'
   Reserved block count:     25600
   Block size:               4096
   Reserved GDT blocks:      1012
   Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
   Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
   ```

   The actual space reserved, in bytes is `Reserved block count` × `Block size`.
2. Tweak this to suit your needs, if you want.

   For instance, to set this to 10 MiB, you can do

   ```
   # tune2fs -r $((10*1024*1024/4096)) /dev/sda1
   ```

   Here 4096 is the block size and 10×1024×1024 is 10 MiB.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I tried your suggestion. First, I run the first command which resulted as 511168 **reserved block count** and 4096 **block size** (approximately 2 GB). Then I adjusted it to be 100 MB with the next command.

However, the disk sizes did not change. When I run the first command, I see it is set to 100 MB. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @iso_9001_, so, if you do `df -h ~` as your `appuser` user, how much free space (the "Avail" column) does it show?

Comment: O.K. I got the problem. By the code you provided, I was able to change root (SDA1) but I required space for appuser (SDA3). I adjusted the code and tried and again and succeeded. Previously, aroun 300MB was reserved for appuser. After the change, I allocated 100 MB and now the free space is aroun 275 MB. Before, it was 75 MB only. This will provide us some time but this is not enough. We need more space. Is there any way to re-allocate pre-allocated disk sizes? For example, can I transfer, say, 10 GB from root to appuser?

Comment: @iso_9001_, well, you seem to confuse matters a bit. A reserved space (for the superuser) on a *single* filesystem is one thing, but passing storage space *between different* filesystems is completely another thing. To do the latter you have to use a layer of virtualization (typically, [`LVM`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) on Linux, but also [`ZFS`](http://zfsonlinux.org/) and `btrfs` provide similar concepts, IIRC)).

Comment: @iso_9001_, basically, with `LVM` you group several block devices (usually physical, like `/dev/sdX` or RAID) into logical groups and then cut virtual devices which have filesystems on them off those groups. The space available in the group might be arbitrarily reallocated between those virtual devices; new storage might be added and then the aqcuired free space given to a virtual device which require it etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, I am not confused. I clearly understand what you suggested earlier, followed the instructions, and created additional 200MB of disk space. However, this is simply not enough. Only 6 GB of disk space is allocated for appuser where 40 GB is allocated for root. Now, I want to re-adjust this total disk space (say, 36GB for appuser, 10 GB for root). The question is, do I have to start over in order to use [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) or can I use it directly on my system? By the way, all these servers and disks are virtual.

Comment: @iso_9001_, supposedly in your case the way to go might be to just migrate: plug a large disk, slowly `rsync` the filesystem on `/dev/sda3` to the new filesystem, then do a final `rsync` while there's no activity on the source FS (it has been remounted in `ro` mode) and then remount the new FS instead the original one.

Comment: @iso_9001_, oh, if the disks are virtual then the answer is "it depends": a partition table usually cuts the disk space starting from its start address towards its end. So if your `/dev/sda3` happens to be the last partition then just resize your disk from your host then extend the partition in the guest and run `resize2fs` on it to occupy the full size. If `/dev/sda3` is not the last, resizing it would require first *moving* the last partition to the end of the disk. Doable with `parted` but slow and *do have backups.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will try to do after the backups. Kind Redards

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking up a utility tool called **gparted** to increase the space allocated to the appuser?

A command line way to address your problem may be found here - worth a look:

[resizing dev/foo_disk and increase space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260620/resize-dev-loop0-and-increase-space)